# Gravity set, but TextView content not centered

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:textColor="@color/very_light_grey"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the text view has

```
android:gravity="center|left"
```

set but the text is not centered vertically (on device but in gui editor it is centered). Instead it sticks to the top left corner of the text view. Any ideas how to center the text vertically?

Comment: Code is perfect, check in other device, I think you paste other code..please paste your full xml code

Comment: android:gravity="centerVerical|left"

Comment: @CapDroid I am on nexus 4

Comment: @artworkadシ I checked, it is working fine. please paste your whole xml code.. In your image there is  two button and in xml only one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below , this is working fine at my side

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="testing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Below is my Output:**

[image]

---

While this answer points out the correct way I had to add a wrapping linear layout to the text view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

this way I could make it work.

Comment: It works in the eclipse gui editor, but not on device

Comment: Did you checked in other device ?

Comment: @artworkadシ please check in other device. may be some device issue

Comment: I have 100% the same xml like you and tested on emulator, same problem. You could try out a list view? Because this is the layout of a list item

Comment: @artworkadシ also working in listview. check image in my answer. please show your all java and xml code related listview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/removeButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:background="#e9e9e9" 
        android:text="hello"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is screenshot of output

[image]

Comment: Check typo: aandroid should be android.

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal it works for me in the gui editor too, but not on device

Comment: please check with the xml I wrote in my answer. It should work for sure @artworkadシ

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity="center"` is correct if you write `center|left`. It will put your text in left only.

Comment: i checked with your xml code only its working just use android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `TextView` gravity to `center_vertical` as below and check

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
    android:background="#e9e9e9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="asdfjhasdfkjhkjashdfjhljh" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:background="#e9e9e9" />

</RelativeLayout>
```